# ColdFusion/HTML text value to Oracle date in format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy'

Tags: html, oracle, coldfusion

How would you take the value of a text box in a form, and, using ColdFusion, convert it to the format 'dd-mmm-yyyy', and then pass it to a Oracle database.  This is for a homework assignment.  Here's the latest thing I tried:

From the ouput page:

```
<cfset date = lsParseDateTime(VISIT_DATE)>
<cfset myDate = DateFormat(#date#, "dd-mmm-yyyy")>  
<cfinsert name="insert_vet" datasource="ORCL" username="xxxx" password="xxxx"
tablename="VISIT"
formfields="VISIT_ID, #myDate#, VISIT_COMMENTS, VISIT_TOTAL, ROCEDURE_ID, 
            ANIMAL_ID, VET_ID, CLIENT_ID">
```

Here's the exception I'm getting:

```
Invalid column name, 10-Feb-2006, was specified.
```

Comment: Whats the col name in the DB? see my answer below once you know this

Comment: the column name is VISIT_DATE

Comment: where is your answer @TimWickstrom.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies here:

```
formfields="VISIT_ID, #myDate#, VISIT_COMMENTS, VISIT_TOTAL, ROCEDURE_ID,
```

You are expected to pass the names of the fields in the  to the insert tag.

...and what are you passing?

The *value* of #myDate#, which is '10-Feb-2006'. The insert tag looks in your submitted form field list, and says, "Yeah, there is no FORM field named '10-Feb-2006', ERROR".

Replace #myDate# with the name of the `<INPUT>` field and you should be fine.

Comment: the name of the input field doesn't store a valid Oracle date format.  Does ColdFusion allow you to access the form array and change the value of one of it's fields?

Comment: @webhound - Yes you can modify FORM fields. But is this a date/time column? If so, the format does not matter. See my response above.

Answer (score 1):

> formfields="VISIT_ID, #myDate#,

To answer your question, [`formfields`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c78.html) should contain the *name* of your field, but you are passing in its value instead. To do what you are asking you just need to modify the *value* of the variable `FORM.VISIT_DATE` before the `cfinsert`.

```
ie <cfset FORM.VISIT_DATE = "... some new value ...">
```

> dd-mmm-yyyy', and then pass it to a Oracle database

That said .. is `VISIT_DATE` is a date/time column? If so, forget about how your IDE displays the values on screen. It is irrelevant. Internally date/time values are stored as numbers not strings. Your IDE just displays those numbers in a more human friendly format like "12-Dec-2011" or "2011-12-01". When modifying date/time columns, always use date *objects*, not strings. See Jason's response for one approach that is compatible with `cfinsert`.

Comment: Oh fudge .. did not see the ton of responses added.

Answer (score 0):

rathen than use DateFormat, use `createODBCDate()`.

```
<cfset myDate = createODBCDate(date)>
```

This will convert your date to a format that can be passed into any DB .. including Oracle

The error you are getting is bacause you are trying to pass the date value in as a column table.

Personally I don't use cfinsert.. I would do (and prefer) something like this.

```
<cfquery name="insert_vet" datsource="#ds#">
  INSERT INTO visit (visit_id, myDate, visit_comments)
  VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#form.visit_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" >,
            <cfqueryparam value="#createODBCDate(form.myDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" >,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.visit_comments#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" >)
</cfquery>
```

You don't need to use `<cfqueryparam` for case of getting it running, but place these before going live to prevent SQL Injection..

**Edit 1**
It does seem to be getting a bit out of hand.. maybe go right back to a clean script and start with a simple insert SQL Statement, and see what that gives you..

```
<cfquery name="insert_vet" datsource="???" username="???" password="???">
  INSERT INTO visit (visit_id, myDate, visit_comments)
  VALUES (#form.visit_id#,#createODBCDate(form.myDate)#, #form.visit_comments#)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I think i tried this earlier... exception:   Invalid column name, {d '2006-02-10'}, was specified.

Comment: Sorry.. I just expanded on my post while you made this comment.. if you still have the code that gave you this error, try putting the value in the SQL in single quotes.. i.e.  '#myDate#' ..

Comment: got a weid one:  invalid host/bind variable name, I used <cfset db = "ORCL"> first.  I also tried just using datasource= "ORCL", which has worked for some of my other queries.  I had this working earlier by using Now() as the value of hidden a text field, I might just go back to that.  This is getting out of hand ;(

Comment: webhound.. you do seem to be getting into a bit of a bind.. time to pear it right back to basics.. see my Edit 1 above.. give that a try and let us know what you get..

Comment: error: column not allowed here... I also tried #DateFormat(form.visit_date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")#   which gave me good looking SQL values, but I got the same message.  At this point, it's just an irritation.  I've reverted back to my old method of always using the current date.  This isn't even important for the assignment.  I'm putting it to bed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect you implemented it incorrectly because the fix to the original `cfinsert` requires only two minor changes.

Comment: All three responses (Shawn, Jason, myself) already pointed out the two issues. Understanding and implementing it is your job ;) If you are still having a problem, update your question to include the new code/error.

Comment: I feel like I tried everybody's suggestions to no avail.  Perhaps, I coded something wrong, but I'm pretty careful and try many things.  I think that the ColdFusion and Oracle server is pretty old.  I tried using some current validation tags and received errors.  I'm not a server expert, but I'm guessing ours has a quirky setup since it can be accessed by almost anyone in the cs program with very little restriction.  Our professor told us we didn't even have to try inserts (probably because he doesn't want to answer a bunch of questions about ColdFusion). Thanks, again for helping.

Comment: @webhound - Re: "Perhaps, I coded something wrong" - Quite possibly, but we need to *see* the new code to offer suggestions. You can always update your original question and append the new code/error message.

Comment: Webhound, what you are trying to do is pretty basic, and should work regardless of server or DB versions being older ones.  It is going to be a fairly trivial issue.  Where you are at is where we have all been when starting out.. stick with the problem and resolve it.. you will be the better for it.

Comment: +1 to sticking with it. Learning *how* to diagnose problems is as important as learning the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ORacle TO_CHAR method to get what format you want to

example

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;

RETURN 18-SEP-2015
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - The OP wanted to use ColdFusion to insert the data into Oracle rather than using Oracle to get the date out.